# Java multiple line read from console

Tags: java, console

I need to read multiple line from console in java. I have tried so many things but nextLine() always read only first line.

```
    System.out.println("Enter number of patterns:");

    noOfSubPattern = scan.nextInt();

   // System.out.println(noOfSubPattern);

    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter patterns:");
    for(int i = 0; i < noOfSubPattern; i++)
    {

        subPattern += scan.nextLine();

    }
    System.out.println("Subpattern: " + subPattern);
```

My output example:

```
Enter number of patterns:
3
Enter patterns:
ATTC
CTGC
CTTC

Subpattern: ATTCATTCATTC
```

However I need to get this result:

```
Subpattern: ATTCCTGCCTTC
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `subPattern` should probably be a `StringBuilder` instead.  That won't matter in a small case like this, but one should not concatenate `String`s in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code works properly:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String subPattern = "";
System.out.println("Enter number of patterns:");
int noOfSubPattern = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter patterns:");
for(int i = 0; i < noOfSubPattern; i++)
    subPattern = subPattern + scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Subpattern: " + subPattern);
```

Comment: After your answer, I realized that my computer made memory problem. I restarted computer and same code start to work correctly. Sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

`scan.nextLine();` doesn't seem to serve any purpose here.

You should probably initialize `subPattern` as an empty string:

```
String subPattern = "";
```

Comment: Actually, it skips to the end of the line with the number of patterns.

Comment: @EricJablow Yes, you're right. The code seems alright to me then.